# How to set up website with Angular 2 on Github Pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, github-pages

Following the [Angular 2 quickstart tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart), I have created my website and want it to run on Github Pages. However, I currently run it through using the `npm start` command in terminal. What changes do I have to make so that it will load properly after I push it to Github?

Comment: Possibly this tutorial might help: http://developer.telerik.com/featured/quick-angular-2-hosting-angular-cli-github-pages/

Comment: If you use Angular CLI, then there is a [built in way](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#deploying-the-app-via-github-pages) to deploy it on Github pages.

Answer (score 3):

In my humble opinion, Angular2 Quick Start is a pain in the but. Not quick at all !!

I suggest you to start using the Angular2 CLI (the command line tool). It's fast, easy to use, has a built in **build process**.. you get a dist folder.. etc. Only advantages..

The **build process** is important here, because if you want to host your app on GitHub using gh-pages - you can do that with only ***one command:***

```
ng github-pages:deploy
```

But that is the recommended way. In your case here, it's different.

By following the quick start guide, you don't have a build process in place, so instead, you can push the whole angular2-quickstart folder to the git repo, on the gh-pages branch.

**First:** Install git, create a github account and a github repository.

**Second:** using CMD or some terminal, navigate to your `angular2-quickstart` folder, and than run this commands:

**Basic SETUP**

```
git init --> your local, angular2-quickstart folder, becomes a git repository.

git commit -am "messaage: this stuff goes on master branch.."

git remote add origin <your GitHub repository url here> --> this will add the remote url, where you can push and pull.

git push origin master --> your hole folder will be available on GitHub on the master branch
```

**Host your app on GitHub**

```
git checkout -b gh-pages  -> this creates a new branch called gh-pages based of master, and moves you to it.

git commit -am "your commit message" - you must have at least one commit in order to push.

git push origin gh-pages -> this will push the hole gh-pages branch from local repo - to the GitHub repo and hosting servers.
```

Everything present on the gh-pages branch will be available at this url: `http://your-github-username.github.io/your-repository-name/` . It's the same stuff as if it was loading form your Local-host..

You will see lots of files downloaded trough the network calls - this is because no build process it's in place - no minification, no bundling, no nothing.. But works, I tested it! So good luck!

Comment: The second method you recommend requires pushing the node_modules right? so that index.html has access to systemjs. Where can I find a build process to fix that?

Comment: @David Silva if you don't have a build process - then you must push node_modules folder also. (maybe is required to remove it form `.gitignore` ) But this is bad practice, and more time consuming. Please use Angular2 CLI instead. There is no `system.js` anymore - it has been changed to `webpack`.

Comment: @alon, when I run the deploy, my local version gets replaced by the production version. Is that a bug or do I have to re-clone it each time.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna give up on this :P @alon from what I've seen in the slack and other conversations ng-cli is not super ready yet, is very hard to migrate a project into cli and is not very compatible with other things, and given how much the project I have I'm gonna skip. Thanks!

Comment: Also, if anyone else is interested, there's an option to use this https://github.com/systemjs/builder I can't tinker with it now because of time constrains but if someone figures it out let me know!